# How to Copy and move files and folders in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can we copy and move folders in one folder to another folder.

```
void BtncopyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string filename=@"E:\\Files\\Reports\\R^ECG^_0_1688^Jones^^_20160711065157_20160711065303 - Copy (4) - Copy.pdf";
   string sourcepath=@"E:\\Anusha";
   string targetpath=@"E:\\Anusha\\aaa";

   string sourcefile= System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcepath,filename);
   string destfile= System.IO.Path.Combine(targetpath,filename);
   if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetpath))
   {
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetpath);
   }
   System.IO.File.Copy(sourcefile, destfile, true);
   if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcepath))
   {
      string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcepath);

      // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
      foreach (string s in files)
      {
         // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
         filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
         destfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetpath, filename);
         System.IO.File.Copy(s, destfile, true);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist");
   }
}
void BtnmoveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String path = "E:\\Files\\25-11-2017";          
   String path2 = "E:\\Anusha\\aaa\\25-11-2017";

   if (!File.Exists(path)) 
   {
      {
         // This statement ensures that the file is created, 
         // but the handle is not kept. 
         using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) {}
      }

      System.IO.Directory.Move("E:\\Files\\25-11-2017",@"E://Anusha//aaa");

      // Move the file.
      File.Move(path, path2); 
      MessageBox.Show("File Moved");
   }
}
```

I have the above code to copy and move the folder,I am not getting any compiling errors. However, when i am trying to click on button on the output form it was showing as termination.

**Update**

Code works with out any error but it was getting termination Error as cannot create a file as it is already exists

Comment: What do you mean by `showing as termination`.. do you mean the application crashed?

Comment: if any of the files are open you havent allowed for that and it would crash most likely

Comment: Could be you don't have permission. Try run as admin.

Comment: @It's saying ass can't create a file as  it is already exists for move and for copy its showing as concern folder name is a directory not a file, DO you nee to copy the new folder on the desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I am seeing a lot of problems here.

1) In the line

```
System.IO.Directory.Move("E:\\Files\\25-11-2017",@"E://Anusha//aaa");
```

you are using `//` as directory separator in the second argument. You should change it to

```
System.IO.Directory.Move("E:\\Files\\25-11-2017","E:\\Anusha\\aaa");
```

2) Sometimes you are using verbatim strings incorrectly. For example, in the line

```
string sourcepath=@"E:\\Anusha";
```

you are using a verbatim string which means that the compiler ignores the escape sequences in that string. Hence, your application later won't find that path. Instead, use one of the following:

```
string sourcepath=@"E:\Anusha";
string sourcepath="E:\\Anusha";
```

3) The structure of your BtnmoveClick is quite weird. The line

```
System.IO.Directory.Move("E:\\Files\\25-11-2017","E:\\Anusha\\aaa");
```

moves the contents of `E:\files\25-11-2017` to `E:\Anusha\aaa`, **but only if the latter does NOT exist yet. If it already exists, that line will cause an exception** (which probably makes your application terminate).

Furthermore, after you already have moved the directory contents in the line shown above, you are again trying to move something in the line

```
File.Move(path, path2);
```

But `path` and `path2` are strings which describe directories, not files, so I wouldn't do it that way. Furthermore, since you already have moved the directory (more precise: its contents) in the previous line, I am asking myself what exactly the purpose of that line is.

I didn't look into your BtncopyClick yet, so let's concentrate on BtnmoveClick for now. Please try to fix the issues described so far, and if you have further issues, report back.

As a general recommendation: If you really want to learn C#, then don't copy-and-paste randomly selected examples; you'll never learn anything useful that way. Instead, read the documentation of the .net framework on MSDN or read a good book - this will gain you a deep understanding.

Comment: I have taken your suggestions thanks for help .

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

[How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders)

You can use [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file), [System.IO.Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.7.2), [System.IO.FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo), and [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) classes from the [System.IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace.